# Drupal user_external_login_register

Tags: drupal

The [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_external_login_register/6) reads:

> Helper function for authentication
>   modules. Either login in or registers
>   the current user, based on username.
>   Either way, the global $user object is
>   populated based on $name.

It seems to me that this function does not actually perform a login (it does not trigger the user_hook with op=login.  It does not call user_external_login or even user_authenticate_finalize.

Am I interpreting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the code, and it doesn't invoke `hook_user() op = 'login'`. You can do that in your own module though.

Look at [`user_module_invoke()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_module_invoke/6) to do this.

Comment: agreed that it doesnt invoke login -- wouldn't this imply that the func is not really performing login?

Comment: Well it does log the user in, the user will not be anonymous anymore, but he will be his user, has access, and things he do, will be accredited him. But other modules wont get a chance to react on it.

Answer (score 0):

It does log the user in. 
Last lines in code,

```
     // Log user in.
  $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
  user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
```

, seems to say that, in spite of submitting a wrong password.

System seems to create a user (named like that name provided in the login form) and save locally whichever wrong password provided (which will be, then, the "right" password).

If you do not take further action, then, it will not even care about an external authentication source and the real onwer of that name will not be able to log in later...

Scary, uh?